# Is it possible to create two ranges for a randint in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to Python and am trying to find a way to generate two separate, random numbers. I'm using a randint with a range of 0 - 100:

`(randint(0, 100))`

Is there any way possible for a newbie to make a second range or randint?

Comment: ... just call `randint(0, 100)` again?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure if that would work or not. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to make sure you will get 2 *different* numbers,use the `sample` function, and it would return a list:

```
random.sample(range(0, 101), k=2)
```

Answer (score -4):

Just call `randint(0, 100)` again.